# Why does my Google Calendar event, with "no end date" suddenly end?

Tags: google-calendar

I created a recurring event on my Google Calendar for "Work" from 8 am to 5 pm, that repeats every weekday, when I started my current job back in 2013. Today, I was making plans to take a day off, and when I went into my Google calendar to remove the event from that day, I noticed that the series abruptly stops at the end of next week.

I opened up the event and verified that it is still set to "No end date". I tried manually changing the end date to a specific date, a few months in the future, but no matter what I do, it still just stops at the end of next week.

**What is going on here?**

Answer (score 13):

Currently, Google Calendar limits recurring events to have a maximum of **730** occurrences in the series<sup>[[1]](https://web.archive.org/web/20160825115901/https://sites.google.com/a/whps.org/whps-google-classroom/google-calendar/5-1-add-appointments-and-events)</sup>. Unfortunately, they don't do a very good job of communicating this limitation in the UI. There are 3 options for a recurring series' end: "Never", "After _____ occurrences", and "On _____". If you choose "Never", or enter a number of occurrences greater than 730, or choose an end date that, based on your recurrence pattern, would put the number of occurrences above 730, Calendar does not provide any indication that your expectations will not be met; it simply accepts your input, but still limits the number of events actually displayed to 730.

You have two options:

- Create a new copy of your recurring event, starting the week after next. It might be a good idea to manually enter "730 occurrences", as a reminder to yourself when this happens again 146 weeks (~2 years, 10 months) from now.
- Move the start date of your existing event to a later date (if you aren't concerned about keeping the event's history, e.g. other vacation days you previously took).

Comment: It seems the 730 event limit has been around since at least 2013. https://support.google.com/calendar/forum/AAAAd3GaXpE93V6fILk_J4

Comment: Even though Google Calendar’s UI has this limit, when viewing a Google Calendar synced to an iOS device, the iOS device ignores the limit and correctly shows the data. So the data in Google Calendar is stored correctly, it just doesn’t support its own data as well as Apple does.

Comment: @binki just to be clear, the behavior can be seen even in the Google calendar web app - so it's not, for example, just a bug in the Google Calendar app on smartphones, it's a limitation that's apparently deeply rooted in the design of the database in which Google stores the calendar data.

Comment: @DanHenderson I know. It’s a bug in both the app and webapp. It cannot display its own data correctly. It’s unfortunate because it makes third party apps which correctly handle its data look wrong even though Google Calendar is wrong. I consider the example of how iOS Calendar handles the data correctly to be proof of this.